# Easy question on Logic and Modes Ponens

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, formal-proofs

I got confused with these:

using ONLY this three axioms and Modus Ponens:$$1. \ F \implies (G\implies F) \\ 2. \ (F \implies (G\implies H))\implies ((F \implies G)\implies (F \implies H)) \\
3. \ (\neg G \implies \neg F)\implies ((\neg G\implies F)\implies G)$$

I need to prove:
$$4. \ (F \implies G)\implies ((G \implies H)\implies(F\implies H))\\$$
I see it intuitively, but I have to use ONLY the axioms.

I started like this:
$$1. F \implies G\\2. \ H \implies (F \implies G) \ by \ (1)\\3.((H\implies F)\implies (H \implies G)) \ by \ (2)$$
but that is not what I want

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you want a formal proof or is it enough to prove that $$\vdash (F \to G)\to ((G \to H)\to(F\to H))?$$ Have you learned the deduction theorem yet?

Comment: @GitGud yes, it is enough. I can't use it, that's the point. I am supposed to use only the three axioms above.

Comment: You can use the deduction theorem to get a formal proof, that's the point of the theorem. Have you learned about it? Did you understand its proof?

Comment: @GitGud Oh, I think I don't need a formal proof.

Comment: You're contradicting yourself for the second time. There are two ways to read the question. One is "Provide a formal proof of $(F \to G)\to ((G \to H)\to(F\to H))$" (which corresponds to using only the axioms) the other is "Prove that $\vdash (F \to G)\to ((G \to H)\to(F\to H))$ (however you like)". I believe you want a formal proof.

Comment: @GitGud Oh, ok. I need a formal one then, using the deduction thm.

Comment: You can't use the deduction theorem in a formal proof, when a formal proof is defined as sequence of formulas which starts with the axioms and ends with the theorem and every step is either an axiom or is provable from the axioms of modus ponens and substitution alone.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/290725/proof-of-transitivity-in-hilbert-style) you can find the proof of the "derived rule" ; $A→B,B→C⊢A→C$. With *Deduction Th* it is straightforward to derive the tautology; without it, we have to follow the "instruction" provided by the proof of the *Deduction Th*.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/716122/proof-%c2%acq-%e2%86%92-%c2%acp-from-premise-p-%e2%86%92-q-using-deductive-system-modus-ponens) you can find the first two "steps" in the proof of $⊢(F→G)→((G→H)→(F→H))$ without *DT*, i.e. the proof of $(F→G)⊢(G→H)→(F→H)$.

Comment: See the answer to this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1065674/super-simple-question-on-logic-and-modus-ponens) for a proof without *deduction Theorem*.

Answer (score 0):

The automated theorem prover OTTER has found a 10 step, level 5 proof:

```
----> UNIT CONFLICT at   4.26 sec ----> 11611 [binary,11610.1,2.1] $F.

Length of proof is 10.  Level of proof is 5.

---------------- PROOF ----------------

1 [] -P(i(x,y))| -P(x)|P(y).
2 [] -P(i(i(a,b),i(i(b,c),i(a,c)))).
3 [] P(i(x,i(y,x))).
4 [] P(i(i(x,i(y,z)),i(i(x,y),i(x,z)))).
5 [hyper,1,4,4] P(i(i(i(x,i(y,z)),i(x,y)),i(i(x,i(y,z)),i(x,z)))).
7 [hyper,1,3,4] P(i(x,i(i(y,i(z,u)),i(i(y,z),i(y,u))))).
8 [hyper,1,3,3] P(i(x,i(y,i(z,y)))).
16 [hyper,1,4,7] P(i(i(x,i(y,i(z,u))),i(x,i(i(y,z),i(y,u))))).
18 [hyper,1,5,8] P(i(i(x,i(i(y,x),z)),i(x,z))).
42 [hyper,1,16,16] P(i(i(x,i(y,i(z,u))),i(i(x,i(y,z)),i(x,i(y,u))))).
56 [hyper,1,3,18] P(i(x,i(i(y,i(i(z,y),u)),i(y,u)))).
230 [hyper,1,42,3] P(i(i(i(x,y),i(z,x)),i(i(x,y),i(z,y)))).
431 [hyper,1,18,56] P(i(i(i(x,y),z),i(y,z))).
11610 [hyper,1,431,230] P(i(i(x,y),i(i(y,z),i(x,z)))).
11611 [binary,11610.1,2.1] $F.
```

Interestingly enough, there exists at least two proofs with a greater level, but which have less steps.  OTTER found a 9 step, level 7 proof:

```
 ----> UNIT CONFLICT at   0.17 sec ----> 514 [binary,513.1,2.1] $F.

 Length of proof is 9.  Level of proof is 7.

 ---------------- PROOF ----------------

 1 [] -P(i(x,y))| -P(x)|P(y).
 2 [] -P(i(i(a,b),i(i(b,c),i(a,c)))).
 3 [] P(i(x,i(y,x))).
 4 [] P(i(i(x,i(y,z)),i(i(x,y),i(x,z)))).
 5 [hyper,1,4,4] P(i(i(i(x,i(y,z)),i(x,y)),i(i(x,i(y,z)),i(x,z)))).
 8 [hyper,1,3,3] P(i(x,i(y,i(z,y)))).
 14 [hyper,1,5,8] P(i(i(x,i(i(y,x),z)),i(x,z))).
 24 [hyper,1,3,14] P(i(x,i(i(y,i(i(z,y),u)),i(y,u)))).
 56 [hyper,1,14,24] P(i(i(i(x,y),z),i(y,z))).
 120 [hyper,1,3,56] P(i(x,i(i(i(y,z),u),i(z,u)))).
 125 [hyper,1,56,5] P(i(i(x,y),i(i(x,i(y,z)),i(x,z)))).
 275 [hyper,1,4,120] P(i(i(x,i(i(y,z),u)),i(x,i(z,u)))).
 513 [hyper,1,275,125] P(i(i(x,y),i(i(y,z),i(x,z)))).
 514 [binary,513.1,2.1] $F.
```

And a 7 step, level 6 proof:

```
 ----> UNIT CONFLICT at   0.37 sec ----> 2045 [binary,2044.1,2.1] $F.

 Length of proof is 7.  Level of proof is 6.

 ---------------- PROOF ----------------

 1 [] -P(i(x,y))| -P(x)|P(y).
 2 [] -P(i(i(a,b),i(i(b,c),i(a,c)))).
 3 [] P(i(x,i(y,x))).
 4 [] P(i(i(x,i(y,z)),i(i(x,y),i(x,z)))).
 7 [hyper,1,3,4] P(i(x,i(i(y,i(z,u)),i(i(y,z),i(y,u))))).
 13 [hyper,1,4,7] P(i(i(x,i(y,i(z,u))),i(x,i(i(y,z),i(y,u))))).
 25 [hyper,1,13,13] P(i(i(x,i(y,i(z,u))),i(i(x,i(y,z)),i(x,i(y,u))))).
 29 [hyper,1,13,3] P(i(i(x,y),i(i(z,x),i(z,y)))).
 85 [hyper,1,25,3] P(i(i(i(x,y),i(z,x)),i(i(x,y),i(z,y)))).
 357 [hyper,1,29,85] P(i(i(x,i(i(y,z),i(u,y))),i(x,i(i(y,z),i(u,z))))).
 2044 [hyper,1,357,3] P(i(i(x,y),i(i(y,z),i(x,z)))).
 2045 [binary,2044.1,2.1] $F.
```